# Organize all dialogs in one package QGIS 3 Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, modulenotfounderror

To organize better the code in my QGIS 3 Plugin, I tried to put all dialogs in one package called `dialogs`, but when I open QGIS it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dialogs'`

This is the code I used to import the Dialog class in the "main" file, where there's run method (`luniPlugin.py` in this case)

```
from dialogs.select_feature_dialog import SelectFeatureDialog
```

(and the same for the others dialogs)

This is the folder where the project is:

[image]

And, finally, this is the content of the folder "dialogs":

[image]

Since python compiler has not given me errors, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this "unpacking" in a QGIS Plugin or if it's simple my mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
pluginname/                   top-level package
    __init__.py               initialize the package
    luniPlugin.py
    dialogs/                  sub module
       select_feature_dialog.py
       .
       .
```

You have to specify explicitly sub module in the same package using `.`(dot).

Use `.dialogs.select_feature_dialog` **(Relative import)**:

```
from .dialogs.select_feature_dialog import SelectFeatureDialog
```

Or, you can use an absolute path for sub module. In this case you have to specify the package/plugin name. **(Absolute import)**:

```
from pluginname.dialogs.select_feature_dialog import SelectFeatureDialog
```

For more information, review Python [Packages documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).